# Garbage collection only every third cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

In my AngularJS 1.5 app, I've discovered a very strange memory behavior.

I set up a very simple test:
An almost empty template being state 1 (using Angular ui-router) which only forwards to state 2.
The template for state 2 is filled with a rather large dummy table by an array inside the scope.
In the controller:

```
$scope.foodahoo = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                var obj = {};
                for(var j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                    obj['prop' + j] = 'value' + j;
                }
                $scope.foodahoo.push(obj);
            }
```

In the template:

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="myobj in foodahoo">
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in myobj">{{key}}: {{value}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Expected memory behavior: on state 1, heap starts at a low level, goes up when I go to state 2, goes down to the same low level when going back to state 1 and so forth - regardless how often I repeat that cycle.

However, the actual behavior is like so (recorded in Chrome Dev Tools):

[image]

Marked in red are state changes from state 1 to state 2.
It seems like at the beginning memory is simply added without being garbage collected in between. However, then, every third cycle, right in the middle of loading the state, Chrome thinks: "Oops, I consume too much memory, let's do free some garbage."
However, even then, the heap doesn't reach the level it had at the starting point (at state 1).

Replacing `$scope` with `this` and `controller as ...` has no effect: the result is the same. Whereas, putting in plain HTML shows normal behavior.

So, my questions are:
Is this just a Chrome quirk? Or normal browser behavior? Or do I actually have a general memory problem with my `$scope` ? If yes: How can I investigate this further? Heap profile comparison didn't give me any insights yet.

Comment: GC is very complex, and has lots of heuristics or quirks as you call them.

Comment: Well, since all the memory is free eventually and does not keep accumulating forever, I'd say that you don't have any problem.

Comment: @Bergi Well, not all memory gets free again. It seems that it never reaches the "starting level". It does almost, but not quite.

Comment: @cis It seems that GC happens always during the state transition. The part of the table that is already created there won't be collected, that's why it never reaches 0. Still, the whole table is eventually collected after the next cycle. I didn't mean to say that everything is necessarily freed at the same time.